# Best way to iterate folders and subfolders

Tags: c#, directory, subdirectory

What's the best way to iterate folders and subfolders to get file size, total number of files, and total size of folder in each folder starting at a specified location?

Comment: Just two words: foreach and recursion..

Comment: @Bugai13 - That's a good suggestion for CS homework, but the .Net framework already includes that functionality. As an aside, moving away from iterating over collections/enumerables and towards querying collections/enumerables, or even giving the collection/enumerable the work to do is the correct way to solve that problem in a modern context.

Comment: please fix the title typo: i**n**terate and capitalize the first letter.

Comment: @Pekka at first I wanted to explore different ways but I guess I'll stick with c#

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use [Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx). The bottom of that page includes an example that's fully recursive.

**Note:** Use Chris Dunaway's answer below for a more modern approach when using .NET 4 and above.

```
// For Directory.GetFiles and Directory.GetDirectories
// For File.Exists, Directory.Exists
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

public class RecursiveFileProcessor 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        foreach(string path in args) 
        {
            if(File.Exists(path)) 
            {
                // This path is a file
                ProcessFile(path); 
            }               
            else if(Directory.Exists(path)) 
            {
                // This path is a directory
                ProcessDirectory(path);
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid file or directory.", path);
            }        
        }        
    }

    // Process all files in the directory passed in, recurse on any directories 
    // that are found, and process the files they contain.
    public static void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory) 
    {
        // Process the list of files found in the directory.
        string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
        foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
            ProcessFile(fileName);

        // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
        string [] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
        foreach(string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
            ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
    }
    
    // Insert logic for processing found files here.
    public static void ProcessFile(string path) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processed file '{0}'.", path);       
    }
}
```

Comment: One caveat: Directory.GetFiles() can be *extremely* slow with directories containing large numbers of files (10's to 100's of thousands).  In these cases the fastest way I've found so far is actually to start a process to run a `dir` command and redirect the output and parse it (or pipe into a file and read that). Granted, I don't consider this unless I expect 50,000+ files in a single directory.

Comment: Actually it may be quicker to pinvoke `FindFirstFile` etc instead of using `dir` although I'm sure .NET thunks down to this anyhow.

Answer (score 61):

If you're using .NET 4, you may wish to use the `System.IO.DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories` and `System.IO.DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` methods. If you use the `Directory.GetFiles` method as other posts have recommended, the method call will not return until it has retrieved ALL the entries. This could take a long time if you are using recursion.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413232.aspx):

> The `EnumerateFiles`and `GetFiles` methods differ as follows:
>
> - When you use `EnumerateFiles`, you can start enumerating the collection of `FileInfo` objects before the whole collection is
>     returned.
> - When you use `GetFiles`, you must wait for the whole array of `FileInfo` objects to be returned before you can access the array.
>
> Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories,
>   `EnumerateFiles` can be more efficient.

Comment: Had to skip dozen of examples of using GetDirectory() to find this one. With >50k directories it was too slow. Thanks for the rare example that saved my day.

Answer (score 8):

To iterate through all directories sub folders and files, no matter how much sub folder and files are.

```
string [] filenames;
 fname = Directory.GetFiles(jak, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();
```

then from array you can get what you want via a loop or as you want.

Comment: This will infinite loop if there's a loop in your folder structure:  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example using Peter's suggestion above and recursion.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileSystemUtils
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string folderPath = "C:\\docs";

            DirectoryInfo startDir = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

            RecurseFileStructure recurseFileStructure = new RecurseFileStructure();
            recurseFileStructure.TraverseDirectory(startDir);
        }

        public class RecurseFileStructure
        {
            public void TraverseDirectory(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
            {
                var subdirectories = directoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories();

                foreach (var subdirectory in subdirectories)
                {
                    TraverseDirectory(subdirectory);
                }

                var files = directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles();

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    HandleFile(file);
                }
            }

            void HandleFile(FileInfo file)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", file.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate through files and folders you would normally use the [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383574.aspx) and [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) types. The FileInfo type has a Length property that returns the file size in bytes.

I think you must write your own code to iterate through the files and calculate the total file size, but it should be a quite simple recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you will need to perform validation checks.

```
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
int fileCount = fileNames.Count();
long fileSize = fileNames.Select(file => new FileInfo(file).Length).Sum(); // in bytes
```

Comment: What type of validation checks

Comment: @rod: check if `Directory.Exists` (otherwise, `DirectoryNotFoundException`). I can't think of anything else, but maybe I missed something.