# Navigation inside Folders in Web Page

Tags: c#, ranorex

I have a web page and there is Folder structure inside that web table. I am looking for code(preferably C#) which can navigate deep inside the First parent Folder loop by loop and then navigate back to parent and return the folder names and then start with the second parent. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following websites. I know that there are no folders inside a web table, but I think you will find a general idea how to solve your issue:

- [Best way to iterate folders and subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181405/best-way-to-iterate-folders-and-subfolders)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142292/Recursive-methods-in-Csharp

I hope this helps.