# Iterate through two directories

Tags: c#

I am looking to iterate through two directories. I am aware of options available [to iterate through each directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181405/best-way-to-iterate-folders-and-subfolders) and storing the list of all the details it found within it in a list. I was wondering if there is a better way of achieving this in C# without iterating through each directory and storing the details in a separate list.The requirement is while iterating through one of the directory for all its contents, I want to compare each item in that directory to the one in the second directory

Comment: Why do you need this? Do you just want arbitrary pairs of files? Or do you want to find something like matching files? It could be as simple as `Directory.EnumerateFiles(...).Zip(Directory.Enumerate.Files(...), ...)...`...

Comment: What is your exact requirement? It may be solved with linq joins.

Comment: @CodeCaster i haven't tried that as i didn't even know whether there was any other of achieving what I need other than what I have mentioned.

Comment: @Haukinger this is still not simultaneously, he should consider a multithreaded approach in order to acheive this

Comment: This question, as asked, both feels too broad and smells of being an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Instead of asking how to achieve some unknown problem (A), you are asking about a solution you think might work (simultaneous iteration (B)).  Without knowing what A is, it's not really possible to tell you how to implement B.

Comment: @Arshad I am trying to iterate through the contents of two directory paths as the same time

Comment: "the same time" is a loaded phrase. The I/O system doesn't allow for simultaneous reads, so it's impossible in any language. Clearly state what you're *actually trying to do*.

Comment: @Pete Please mention your objective. What you want to do by iterating 2 directories simultaneuosly?

Comment: @Claies it isn't some thing unknown. I just was curious whether it is something that can be achieved in C# because I know that it can be done in other languages.

Comment: right, the **potential solution** is known, since it is what you are asking about, but the **problem** you plan to use this solution for is what is unknown.  multiple people have asked you to explain **why** you need to iterate two directories at the same time, to which you just keep saying "because I want to" or "you can do it in other languages", which doesn't explain anything at all.

Comment: @Claies the answer to your "why" is while iterating through one of the directory for all its contents, I want to compare each item in that directory to the one in the second directory.

Comment: ok, so that's what you should put in the question body.  That seems like something reasonable to accomplish, and there are probably quite a few patterns in place already that can achieve this.

Comment: Question is not very clear. Iterating through a directory is not normally a performance-impacting task. One would normally try multithreading and asynchronous programming

Comment: @Claies could you please mention some of these patterns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is a better way of achieving this in C# without iterating through each directory and storing the details in a separate list.

Use `EnumerateFiles` on both directories, zip-join them, and then run the join through a foreach loop.

```
var firstFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(...);
var secondFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(...);
var joined = firstFiles.Zip(secondFiles, 
  (first, second) => new { First = first, Second = second });
foreach(var pair in joined)
{
   // now do something with pair.First and pair.Second
}
```

Comment: @Pete: A lucky guess; your question was pretty unclear.

Comment: @Pete: Remember, "simultaneous" has a very specific meaning; it implies that two things are actually happening physically at the same time, and that is very hard to do with a single disk. Timings of I/O events can be very tricky; and if you have a performance problem involving high latency waiting on disks, then you don't want simultaneity, you want the opposite. You want an asynchronous workflow.